# Force 2 decimal places precision in ion-input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'd like to always display numbers with **two decimal places precision** in **ion-input**. So that:

```
1.01
1.10
1.20
1.23
```

**are NOT** displayed as:  1.1 and 1.2, but appear as 1.10 and 1.20

My model is:

```
export class HomePage {
   public myValue:number;
}
```

with the html file as follows:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <ion-row margin-right="50px" margin-left="50px">
      <ion-input type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01"
                 [(ngModel)]="myValue" placeholder="0.00"></ion-input>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

I've also tried simply:

```
<ion-input type="number" step="0.01"
                     [(ngModel)]="myValue" placeholder="0.00"></ion-input>
```

It works in the web browser (MacOS, 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)) but does not work on Android (tested on 7.1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I want the same example like yours, I'm using ionic latest version 3.9.2, and typescript version 2.3.4

Answer (score 12):

Store the number as inputted, and format using the [decimal pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html) when outputting the value. This will always display 2dp

`{{ myValue | number:'1.2-2' }}`

If you want to use the pipe within the component itself, perhaps as part of the validation logic, you can inject it.

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
class MyService {

    constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

    twoDecimals(number) {
        return this.decimalPipe.transform(number, '1.2-2');
    }
}
```

***Note:*** You need to set it as a `provider` on `app.module.ts`

*app.module.ts*

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

 providers: [
     DecimalPipe
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
                  **HTML : **                
 <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="defaultQuantity" formControlName="defaultQuantity" (ngModelChange)="changeQuantity($event)">


    ***Function : ***

    import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

    export class OrderPage {

    constructor(public cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef ){}

          changeQuantity(value){
                    //manually launch change detection
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
                    if(value.indexOf('.') !== -1)
                    {
                      this.defaultQuantity = value.substr(0, value.indexOf('.')+3);
                    } else {
                      this.defaultQuantity = value.length > 4 ? value.substring(0,4) : value;
                    }
                 }

    }


        **OUTPUT :** 

                1.01
                1.10
                1.20
                1.23
```